# Is it possible such structure declaration In c

Tags: c, structure

Hii ALL,
         i am new to c and learing structure.I came across to one of structure declaration and have a doubt on its validation ...

```
struct a
{ 
int x;
struct a b;
}
```

is it fine to have such structure declaration and if not then why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A structure cannot contain itself. This simply would not make any sense, since the resultant type will be infinitely large.

In other words, your structure includes an instance of itself, which in turn also includes an instance of itself, which in turn also includes an instance of itself, and so on and so forth ad infinitum...

Form the formal point of view, you are trying to declare a structure member `b` that has *incomplete type*. It is illegal to declare struct members of incomplete type in C.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey but while defining a class, we can create a variable of that class type within the same class

Comment: @AMIT: No, we can't. I don't know where you get that idea. Neither in C nor in C++ you can include class/struct into itself.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because the compiler cannot determine the size of your structure if it is self contained.

What works is:

```
struct a
{
int x;
struct a* b;
}
```

Then you have a pointer to the same structure inside your structure. This can be used e.g. for linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling this you'll get an error similar to:

```
src.c: In function `main':
src.c:4: field `b' has incomplete type
```

Using `struct a *b`, however, is perfectly fine.

http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Nested-structures.html